# В Laravel тесты через curl для тестирования PUT не передаютя значения

Tags: laravel, curl, put

Всем привет,
В Laravel 5.5.0 делаю тесты через curl  и для тестирования PUT в routes/web.php :

```
Route::put('/departments/{id?}', 'DepartmentsController@update');
```

В контроле:

```
$url= $this->testing_host."/departments";   
$ch = curl_init( trim($url) );
echo '<pre>$ch::'.print_r($ch,true).'</pre>';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/json' ] );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($departmentData));
$curlReturnedData   = curl_exec( $ch );
echo '<pre>$curlReturnedData::'.print_r($curlReturnedData,true).'</pre>';
$resultArray= json_decode($curlReturnedData);
...
curl_close( $ch );
```

И в DepartmentsController.php:

```
public function update( Request $request )
{
    $paramsArray= $request->all(); // вызывется, но массив пустой как и $_POST с  $_GET
    ...
```

А как правильно?

Спасибо !

Comment: Никто еще не отменял мануалов, [Laravel  HttpTests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/http-tests)

Comment: За ссылочку спасибо но решения я там не нашел. Ткните плиз...

Comment: В тестах, так не пойдети  ```$this->json('PUT', '/path', ['parms_1' => 'Test']);```